# How to use special characters in XML tag like <abc-name> using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have one requirement where I need to generate XML from JAXB.
I have used basic object where we have only key value pair with parent child relationship but never encountered situation like below. 
Expected XML

```
<swExtended>
    <swx-mandatory>FALSE</swx-mandatory>
    <swx-period/>
</swExtended>
```

In Java Object, I dont know how to name tag with special character `<swx-mandatory>` while defining java variable.

Comment: You can use the JAXB annotations to specify what name an XML element gets. For example, if I have a field in my Java class called `dave` and I want that to be output as `dave-123` in my XML, I could annotate that field with `@XmlElement(name = "dave-123")`

Comment: Oh. Let me try this.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Earlier I was facing another problem after defining `XmlElement(name = "dave-123")` on variables.

**com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Class has two properties of the same name**

but now it is working after moving this annotation on getter methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BretC mention, Answer was very simple

```
@XmlElement(name = "dave-123")
```